# CString Parsing Carriage Returns

Tags: c++, parsing, mfc, cstring

Let's say I have a string that has multiple carriage returns in it, i.e:

394968686
100630382
395950966
335666021

I'm still pretty amateur hour with C++, would anyone be willing to show me how you go about: parsing through each "line" in the string ? So I can do something with it later (add the desired line to a list). I'm guessing using Find("\n") in a loop?

Thanks guys.

Comment: Carriage return (\r) is not newline (\n). Before you write your loop it's pretty important to find out which one (or both) that you have in your string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try it using stringstream. Notice that you can overload the getline method to use any delimeter you want.

```
string line;
stringstream ss;
ss << yourstring;
while ( getline(ss, line, '\n') )
{
  cout << line << endl;
}
```

Alternatively you could use the boost library's tokenizer class.

Comment: this is one of the most inefficient ways of parsing a string

Comment: @Gene - What it lacks in computational efficiency, it makes up with simplicity and versatility. Reusing this if your input is a file stream is a breeze.

Answer (score 2):

```
while (!str.IsEmpty())
{
    CString one_line = str.SpanExcluding(_T("\r\n"));
    // do something with one_line
    str = str.Right(str.GetLength() - one_line.GetLength()).TrimLeft(_T("\r\n"));
}
```

Blank lines will be eliminated with this code, but that's easily corrected if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If your string is stored in a c-style char* or `std::string` then you can simply search for `\n`.

```
std::string s;
size_t pos = s.find('\n');
```

You can use `string::substr()` to get the substring and store it in a list. Pseudo code,

```
std::string s = " .... ";
for(size_t pos, begin = 0; 
    string::npos != (pos = s.find('\n'));
    begin = ++ pos)
{
  list.push_back(s.substr(begin, pos));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `stringstream` class in C++.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   string str = "\
                394968686\
                100630382\
                395950966\
                335666021";
   stringstream ss(str);
   vector<string> v;

   string token;
   // get line by line
   while (ss >> token)
   {
      // insert current line into a std::vector
      v.push_back(token);
      // print out current line
      cout << token << endl;
   }
}

Output of the program above:

394968686
100630382
395950966
335666021
```

Note that no whitespace will be included in the parsed token, with the use of operator>>. Please refer to comments below.

Comment: or `string line; while (std::getline(ss, line)) {...}`

Comment: They are not exactly the same. std::getline reads in the whitespace as part of the string as well while overloaded >> won't. It depends on what OP needs though.

Comment: The question is about MFC's CString, not std::string. Don't see how this answer is relevant.

Comment: @Mark, You can always convert a CString to std::string if you want.

Comment: It is ugly transformation from type to type. Why don't you offer converting CString to array of chars (or wchars) then make loop on each character and finally converting back to CString?

Comment: @George, What do you want by "loop on each character"? Are you sure it's related to the OP's problem?